# messageComposeViewController didFinishWithResult delegate method not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I have a view controller "Paircontroller" that presents an MFMessageComposeViewController, as so:

```
NSArray *recpts = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:phone.text, nil];

MFMessageComposeViewController *mcontr = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc]init];
mcontr.body = @"Sign up for our app!";
mcontr.recipients = recpts;
mcontr.subject = @"hey!";
mcontr.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:mcontr animated:YES completion:^{
}];
```

this view controller's interface looks as follows:

```
@interface PairViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate,CustomIOS7AlertViewDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate>

@end
```

Within the view-controller's implementation, I have defined the delegate method - `(void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result`

as follows:

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result
{
    switch (result) {
        case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Cancelled");
            break;
        case MessageComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"unknown error sending m");
            break;
        case MessageComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Message sent successfully");

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
}
```

However, the delegate method is not being called (breakpoint not hit, and NSLogs not being hit either).

Can someone help me out on why this is not working?

Thanks!

C

Comment: Is that message composer dismissed after sending the message ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the following change should work. `MFMessageComposeViewController` is a `UINavigationController` subclass, so in your original code you are setting `UINavigationControllerDelegate` to self.

```
mcontr.messageComposeDelegate = self;
```